# Escape tags without converting characters

Tags: python, html, email, jinja2

I am using [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) to safely render templates for email messages from a web contact form. The problem is the characters   &, <, >, ', and " are converted to HTML-safe sequences. So

> That's all folks!

becomes

```
That&#39;s all folks!
```

I want to remove any HTML tags to prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) without any without any character encoding. Is that possible in jinja2?

Note: the striptags [utility](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#utilities) also converts characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. How would you deal with a message such as `That's only true when x<y and x>0`. The parts between `<` and `>` are part of the message, but could be interpreted as an (borked) HTML tag.

It's up to the browser to read `That&#39;s all folks!` and display it correctly by decoding the characters.

Comment: I guess what I need to investigate is why gmail isn't rendering it properly.